# meson cross compile issue; compile arm64 wayland from linux x86; fails on simple header file

Tags: cross-compiling, meson-build, wayland

I am attempting to cross compile wayland for arm64 on a linux x86 host system. Wayland uses a build system called meson, and this build system is not working properly in this configuration. I have created the following cross file. Note that there is no exe wrapper available.

`

```
[binaries]
c = 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc'
cpp = 'aarch64-linux-gnu-g++'
ar = 'aarch64-linux-gnu-ar'
strip = 'aarch64-linux-gnu-strip'

[properties]
sizeof_int = 4
sizeof_wchar_t = 4
sizeof_void* = 4

alignment_char = 1
alignment_void* = 4
alignment_double = 4

has_function_printf = true

[host_machine]
system = 'linux'
cpu_family = 'x86_64'
cpu = 'x86_64'
endian = 'little'
```

`

Upon attempting to invoke meson, the following occurs:

`

```
$ meson setup --cross-file meson_cross_compile.txt build-nxp
The Meson build system
Version: 0.45.1
Source dir: /disk1/linux/6.0.9/system/wayland
Build dir: /disk1/linux/6.0.9/system/wayland/build-nxp
Build type: cross build

meson.build:83:1: ERROR: lexer
        { 'header': 'sys/signalfd.h', 'symbol': 'SFD_CLOEXEC' },
 ^

A full log can be found at /disk1/linux/6.0.9/system/wayland/build-nxp/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

`

There is no additional information available in the full log. It merely repeats what was already printed:

`

```
Build started at 2022-12-22T18:40:50.973895
Main binary: /usr/bin/python3
Python system: Linux
The Meson build system
Version: 0.45.1
Source dir: /disk1/linux/6.0.9/system/wayland
Build dir: /disk1/linux/6.0.9/system/wayland/build-nxp
Build type: cross build

meson.build:83:1: ERROR: lexer
        { 'header': 'sys/signalfd.h', 'symbol': 'SFD_CLOEXEC' },
 ^
```

`

This makes no sense to me. Looking at the file sys/signalfd.h in the /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include directory, we see this:

`

```
/* Copyright (C) 2007-2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#ifndef _SYS_SIGNALFD_H
#define _SYS_SIGNALFD_H 1

#include <stdint.h>
#include <bits/types/sigset_t.h>

/* Get the platform-dependent flags.  */
#include <bits/signalfd.h>

struct signalfd_siginfo
... (some more irrelevant stuff)
```

`

And if we look at the file bits/signalfd.h which is included from the above, we see the following:

`

```
/* Copyright (C) 2007-2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#ifndef _SYS_SIGNALFD_H
# error "Never use <bits/signalfd.h> directly; include <sys/signalfd.h> instead."
#endif

/* Flags for signalfd.  */
enum
  {
    SFD_CLOEXEC = 02000000,
#define SFD_CLOEXEC SFD_CLOEXEC
    SFD_NONBLOCK = 00004000
#define SFD_NONBLOCK SFD_NONBLOCK
  };
```

`

So SFD_CLOEXEC is clearly defined in this file. And while the cryptic error message meson prints out may mean something to someone, it is incomprehensible to me.  Can anyone who is familiar with this tool please help me understand what is happening here, and how to correct this problem?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your host_machine should be 'aarch64' and your build_machine (does not need to be defined) is 'x86_64'. Read documentation carefully: https://mesonbuild.com/Cross-compilation.html#